# Changing how the attributes are presented in Wicket Datatable

Tags: java, datatable, wicket

I'm developing a new application in Wicket and have run into a small problem.

I'm using a Wicket DataTable, but I want some of the attributes in the dable to be presented different from their "actual" values. For example, I have a Date that is presented as "2011-09-01 00:00", but I want it to be presented as "2011-09-01". How do I do that?

I don't really want to change to POJO or the Date object (maybe override something, somewhere?).

Thanks in advance!

Olle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using a [Converter](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/convert/converters/package-summary.html) configured in your application you will be able to format date the way you want for example.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that this setting is global. It will not only change the format in this particular table, but every place you show Dates (unless you override it locally).

Comment: Yes I was giving this hint as a starting point because he seems to start with Wicket. You have to be careful with application wide `Converter`s

Comment: Yes. It is appropriate some times, but you have to be really sure you want it global.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I'm a beginner at wicket :), in my case, it's suitable with a global setting so this is perfect.

Answer (score 7):

You could create a custom IColumn implementation, that formats the value:

```
class FormatedPropertyColumn<T> extends PropertyColumn<T> {

    private final Format format;

    public FormatedPropertyColumn(IModel<String> displayModel, String sortProperty, String propertyExpression, Format format) {
        super(displayModel, sortProperty, propertyExpression);
        this.format = format;
    }

    public FormatedPropertyColumn(IModel<String> displayModel, String propertyExpression, Format format) {
        super(displayModel, propertyExpression);
        this.format = format;
    }

    @Override
    protected IModel<?> createLabelModel(IModel<T> rowModel) {
        final IModel<?> originalModel = super.createLabelModel(rowModel);
        return new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>() {
            @Override
            public String getObject() {
                Object value = originalModel.getObject();
                return (value != null) ? format.format(value) : null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then you pass the desired format when you instantiate it.

```
List<IColumn> columns = Arrays.asList(
    new FormatedPropertyColumn<POJO>(Model.of("Date"), "date", new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"))
);
```

Comment: A very good answer, except that i would use IConverter instead of Format class.